# Monitoring layer loading progress in OpenLayers

Tags: layers, openlayers, loading

I'm doing an upgrade from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3. In OL2, I was monitoring the loading progress of layers with their `loadstart` and `loadend` events. With grid layers I was even able to show a progress bar using `tileloaded` event.

In OL3, I can't find such events, neither in documentation, nor in the code.

Do you know about some way to at least catch the moment when loading or rendering of a layer is finished?

Comment: A workaround is described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/ScE0A8L6-oc/_107oB8fRu0J

Answer (score 3):

The functionnality has been added recently, see these 2 examples :

- [Tile load events](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/tile-load-events.html)
- [Image load events](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/image-load-events.html?q=load)

Comment: I see this is for Images and Tiles, is it possible to achieve the same for features (Server Vector)?