# Pausing WMS layer auto refresh in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: wms, openlayers

I have an application which has to perform a HTTP request (which will handle some map transformations) before fetching WMS tiles from server.

Is there a way to pause TileWMS auto-refreshing after dragging the map?

Setting invisible or removing and adding the layer will work, but I don't want the layer to disappear while performing the HTTP request. I also tried `setUrl('')` but the layer will also disappear.

I also tried to read OpenLayers source code to define a property to be checked before performing the requests but I couldn't find in code where the requests are made.

Comment: Which version of Openlayers are you use?

Comment: Not bound to any specific version, it is a new app. If you know the answer for any specific version I'll be glad to see your solution. Even if it is in OpenLayers 2.

Comment: you could try just telling the user there is a process going on.  start a "processing graphic" or something and when the map bits load, hide the graphic when it finishes.  A quick search found this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123497/openlayers-3-monitor-layer-loading-progress

Comment: This will go against my requirements of giving a sense of fluidity in the application, I don't want anything to appear or disappear, just the tiles being replaced smoothly with the new ones and not for every drag of the map appear a message of "loading..." or displaying a blank map while new tiles load.

Answer (score 1):

I found some documents that may be able to assist you.

In the [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.1.1/src/ol/source/source.js), Line 167 there is the refresh line.

I found [documentation](https://massbay.mit.edu/scripts/OpenLayers-2.9.1/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html) for OL2 that goes into more detail. You may be able to use this as a reference for your application.

The latest [API Docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html#refresh) for OpenLayers will be your best bet. You will need to change the option from the default of silent.